# Understand how to JavaScript Grayscale Algorithm works (without use jQuery)

Tags: javascript, image, algorithm, grayscale

Today I was looking for an algorithm that converts the color image to grayscale, and the result is not a long search I found the following article

[3 Ways to Turn Web Images to Grayscale](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/grayscale-image-web/)

This article contains the following code snippet

```
var imgObj = document.getElementById('js-image');

function gray(imgObj) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var imgW = imgObj.width;
    var imgH = imgObj.height;
    canvas.width = imgW;
    canvas.height = imgH;

    canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
    var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);

    for (var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++) {
            var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
            var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
            imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
            imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
            imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }
    canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}

imgObj.src = gray(imgObj);
```

Also in this article [http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20170705200146/http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-convert-image-to-grayscale-using-javascript.html) in comments it was suggested to replace:

```
for (var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++) {
        var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
        var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
        imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
        imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
        imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
    }
}
```

with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgPixels.data.length; i = i + 4) {
    var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
    imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
    imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
    imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
}
```

Demo on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n6q9a2c9/

And I have some problems with the understanding of how this algorithm works.

In this code snippet

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgPixels.data.length; i = i + 4) {
    var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
    imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
    imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
    imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
}
```

I understand that `var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3` is formula `(R + G + B) / 3` below is the part that is confusing to me

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgPixels.data.length; i = i + 4) {
```

Why here we increment by 4?

I will be grateful if answer how this algorithm works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas data is provided to you in RGBA (red, green, blue, and a transparency value called 'alpha') interleaved format. Each channel needs a byte per pixel and you have four channels and so there are four values per pixel. Since the channels are interleaved, you increment by 4 to step through the pixels.

References:

- [CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)
- [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) (the structure returned by `getImageData()`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After that I tried to (in jsfiddle) use `console.log(imgPixels)` and get large amounts of data arrays. And with `console.log(imgPixels.data.length)` get number 666000. How to get this number if the image was obtained `500px*333px`

Comment: @Mikhail 500 * 333 * 4 = 666000

Comment: Oh. I think I understood. `500*333=166500` and since for each pixel It has 4 channels (RGBA) multiply `166500*4=666000`

Comment: I'm sorry, but... Can you tell me also about this line (for example in answer) `var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;` (from first code snippet)? In this case (when image `500px*333px`) I have `667332` not `666000` and also in this case not use increment by 4 for skip `alpha` channel

Comment: @Mikhail The pixel data is provided as a one dimensional array. Rather than using a single `for` loop to iterate over that array, they're iterating over `x` and `y` and then converting that into an index, `i`, for the pixel data array. The particular line you ask about does the conversion from `x,y` to an index. I think it might have been more comprehensible if the example used the formula `var i = (y * imgPixels.width + x) * 4;`. Keep in mind that indexes usually start at zero and end just before the array size. Based on the original formula: `332 * 4 * 500 + 499 * 4 = 665996`

Comment: @Mikhail Also, due to some optimizations, the data's size may be larger than what's strictly necessary for the canvas. Compare `imgW` against `imgPixels.width`.

Comment: Thanks. But I drew attention to the fact that in example with single `for` loop we skip alpha channel (because we increment by 4), like this http://pastebin.com/3wz1nX2A and in example with two `for` loop algorithm does not do it (not increment by 4)

Comment: @Mikhail The example with multiple `for` loops does skip the alpha channel, it just integrates that differently with the `* 4` in the index calculation.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong calculation... I get follow results http://pastebin.com/ba670aqX Algorithm skip 2000 indexes?

Comment: @Mikhail Looks right to me. Each row is 500 * 4 = 2000 values long. To get to the right row, you'd need to skip enough values (indexes) to cover the previous rows.

Comment: It has become increasingly clear. I'm sorry for the stupid question but I want to clarify. I schematically depicted process on image here http://i.imgur.com/XU7OvxG.png I understood correctly? Just algorithm with two `for` loops It turned out to be more difficult for me than I thought

Comment: @Mikhail That seems pretty close. This confusion is part of why I said earlier that using the formula `i = (y * imgPixels.width + x) * 4` would be easier to understand than `i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4` that's used in the example. They do the same thing, just my version is mathematically clearer as to what is going on.

Comment: Once again, I'm sorry. But are you couldn't figure it out more schematic (if you have time) like this http://i.imgur.com/XU7OvxG.png or as you wish if this my example is wrong? And yes, your formula really looks clearer. I understand it this way: algorithm skip 2000 indexes but for some reason these indexes convert to grayscale. that's exactly what I can not understand, because the algorithm skip them (indexes), and does not handle and immediately handles `0,1,2,2004,2005,2006,4008,4009,4010,6012,6013,6014...` instead `0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,14...` as in algorithm with one `for` loop

Comment: @Makhail That looks like `x` and `y` are being increased simultaneously. The first set of three comes from coordinates (0,0), the second set from (1,1), the third set from (2,2), and the forth set from (3,3). Are you sure there are no typos in your code? Perhaps mixing up an `x` with `y` or vice-versa?

Comment: Not. Typos no. Algorithm work. I understand that `x` and `y` in `for` loop increased simultaneously. My question about algorithm (by formula) handles only that indexes http://pastebin.com/yhM138hi `0,1,2,2004,2005,2006,4008,4009,4010,6012,6013,6014...` but also need to handle the `0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,14...` indexes, but algorithm skip them. But algorithm really works without errors

Comment: where all indexes between `0, 1, 2` and `2004, 2005, 2006` for example ?

Comment: @Mikhail The other indexes are in there. You'd need to go through all the `x`s up to `imgWidth` to see them. Then reset `x` to `0`, increase `y` by `1`, and repeat. For example: `(498,0) -> 1992`, `(499,0) -> 1996`, `(0,1) -> 2000`, `(1,1) -> 2004`. The `x` and `y` loops are not supposed to increase simultaneously.  http://pastebin.com/i3XLpqK5

Comment: I thought that the `x` and `y` increase simultaneously, so `(0,0), (1,1), (2,2)`. It turns out this is so `(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0)` and so on... Oh... Thank you so much, Ouroborus, for your help and patience